# Proper syntax for nested php "if" statements

Tags: php

I am pretty new to php and I am using a software called CMS Builder that uses a MySQL database. This software provides some templates for displaying data. These templates use this "htmlencode" that I and apparently others on this forum do not know the purpose of.

I have clients in the database, some have a logo and others do not. In each case I want to have the client name or logo linked to the clients website. I want to check if a logo exists, if it does, display it, if it does not then display the client name.

I have edited my code removing my attempt at incorporating the "if" statement into it as I created many php errors trying to do so. Below I have the two statements that display the client name and the logo. I am asking if someone will show me how to incorporate the "if" statement (or, maybe there is a better way using something other than an "if" statement). My code:

```
<a href='<?php echo($clientRecord['clientweb'])?>'<h2><?php echo ($clientRecord['clientname']) ?> </h2></a>

<a href='<?php echo($clientRecord['clientweb'])?>' <img src="<?php echo $upload['thumbUrlPath'] ?>" width="<?php echo $upload['thumbWidth'] ?>" height="<?php echo $upload['thumbHeight'] ?>" alt="" /></a>
```

Comment: What is `htmlencode`? is it your custom function? What returns?

Comment: Start here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.php

Comment: This isn't even close to valid PHP :|

Comment: You need to stop using the alternative syntax. It's never been a good idea, and only gets worse as time goes on.

Comment: @BrandonWamboldt It is valid syntax `foreach` and `endforeach`, `if` and `endif`, I do it quite a bit when I'm working within view files.

Comment: @Matthew Obviously, I use that all the time as well. Read his code, it's not valid PHP at all. He fails to escape PHP, or use PHP tags when needed.

Comment: What is `if echo htmlencode($clientRecord['level'] =='p')` supposed to do?  Why are you checking the return value of `echo` (P.S. it doesn't have one)?

Comment: @BrandonWamboldt sorry I incorrectly assumed you meant the `endforeach` stuff, but now I see that dnevels' missing some `?>` and `<?` tags

Comment: Have a look at: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Comment: @Matthew Ah, no worries. OP doesn't even have correct parentheses around his if statements, and is trying to check the return value of an if statement....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [PSR-2 coding standards](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md)

```
<?php

if ($expr1) {
    // if body
} elseif ($expr2) {
    // elseif body
} else {
    // else body;
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the OP's question (when we don't really even know what's the actual question...)

Comment: It was an attempt to answer "Proper syntax for nested php “if” statements"

Comment: Well, I've removed my downvote anyway. :)

Comment: @DanJ This is technically the correct answer, but not the best answer for the OP

Comment: @DanJ: Though they aren't "nested".  Also the "alternative syntax" is valid, too.

Answer (score 2):

I think you intended something like this:

```
echo $clientRecord['level'];
if ($clientRecord['clientlogo']=='') {  // there is no logo, just print the name
    echo '<h2>' .htmlencode($clientRecord['clientname']) . '</h2>';
} else { // print all logos
    foreach ($clientRecord['clientlogoupload'] as $index => $upload) {
        echo '<a href="' . htmlencode($clientRecord['clientweb']). '"><img src="' $upload['thumbUrlPath'] . '" width="' . $upload['thumbWidth'] . '" height="' . $upload['thumbHeight'] . '" alt="" /></a>';
    }
}
```

I personally never use the `if:endif` `foreach:endforeach` syntax.

Comment: I find the more verbose syntax for blocks is nice if your file is mostly HTML, aka some WordPress templates.